# Server and client running in same app on same UDP socket

Tags: android, sockets, udp, client-server, client

I have a client and server running in the same app, server's thread is always running to listen for the data, but when the client has to send the data  and it creates its own thread my app crashes because it also tries to bind the socket on the same port on which server is listening, I have no other choice other than to use the same port on client and server.How to tackle this problem,and how can I send and receive on the same port with two different sockets? Please help....

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP?

Comment: When using TCP, the client doesn't have to initiate connections from the same port as the one the server is listening on. It just needs to connect to the remote server's socket on that server's port. If I'm requesting a web-page, my browser doesn't attempt to connect *from* port 80, but rather *to* port 80.

Comment: Adding to what @323go said, connect() implicitly assigns a local random port to the client. So, when calling connect(), one can usually skip the bind() step.

Comment: In that case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935358/how-to-bind-2-udp-sockets-to-same-port-one-for-receiving-and-other-for-sending

Comment: @323go am using udp socket which are defined in the separate client and server threads and in different fragments.

Comment: @ManojPandey am using udp socket which are defined in the separate client and server threads and in different fragments.

Comment: That should still not lead to crash. It is okay to handle multiple socket endpoints in multiple threads. YOu might want to show the code-example, where you think the crash might be happening.. But, first make sure you are NOT using the same port for binding the client as well -- basically, you should get rid of the bind() call for the client and simply rely on the connect() call to fetch a local port.